# Return the Yahoo Weather data in different languages

Tags: weather, yahoo-weather-api

I wonder if yahoo weather api supports internationalization to return the data in pt-br and not only in en-us. Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, they only support english
I may recommend you to use this api that has Multilingual support

[API Alternative](https://openweathermap.org/current) And it is free also

Comment: I had already seen this, but it works only for social api, in the weather documentation api I did not find anything similar: /